# Calibrate GY-33 TCS34725 Color Sensor

Tags: arduino, sensors, calibration

How do you properly integrate a GY-33 TCS34725 color sensor calibration into the existing example from the library Adafruit_TCS34725 and example colorview.ino

I tired collecting data from a white background (R:255, G:255, B:255) and a black background (R:0, G:0, B:0) and then used map(sensorValue, sensorMin, sensorMax, 0, 255); but I don't think this is the correct approach to the calibration of this sensor